# What is the Meta key in Spyder shortcuts?

Tags: python, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, anaconda, spyder

I have been using Emacs for a while now and figured that <kbd>Meta</kbd> is <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Problem is Spyder recognizes both <kbd>Meta</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> in its list of shortcuts.

[image]

In fact, the shortcut for **end of line** that works for me turns out to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>, just like the one in Emacs. This is confusing.

Any help will be appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Spyder 3.1.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) According to the Qt documentation:

> On Mac OS X, this [the Meta key] corresponds to the Control keys. On Windows keyboards, this key is mapped to the Windows key.

So we are simply following Qt usage.

*Note*: Qt is the graphical toolkit on top of which Spyder is built.

Comment: This works very poorly though, as Windows_key in combination with most other keys is some built-in Windows command. Almost none of the Meta-shortcuts in Spyder works on Windows, instead Windows is doing all kinds of stuff.

Comment: We're aware of that and we're trying to fix it for Spyder 4.

Comment: so what is the current Meta key on Windows? can it be configured by user? where?

Comment: It's the `Windows` key (it's on my answer above). And no, it can't be configured by the user.